# Controlling the event ElementTypeDuplicated

Tags: revit-api

I am controlling the event "application.ControlledApplication.ElementTypeDuplicated" and this event raise after the name of the new type is imputed, but after that I would like to override the result of the dialog box ( ID: "IDD_SYMBOL_ATTRIB") that were raised before the event ElementTypeDuplicated. I already try to get a Object Args and override the result inside the method that is suubscribing the event ElementTypeDuplicated, but is not working. Is there a way of doing this?

Example:

```
    public void OnElementTypeDuplicated(object o, ElementTypeDuplicatedEventArgs args)
    {
        //doing things 
        duplicatingTypeArgs.OverrideResult(0);

            }
        }
    }

    public void OnDialogDuplicatingELement(object o, DialogBoxShowingEventArgs args)
    {

        if (args.DialogId=="IDD_SYMBOL_ATTRIB")
        {
                    duplicatingTypeArgs = args;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested this yet, but how about implementing IUpdater with "Element.GetChangeTypeElementAddition" instead subscribing to the duplicating type event

Comment: I try to use this, but it seems to produce the same result because the DialogBox "IDD_SYMBOL_ATTRIB" remain open and do not let me make any transaction. I need a way to make a transaction after my Wall Type duplicated.

Comment: I use this framework and add a Subtransaction to deal with the changes in the database of the document. I was using  the Transaction class and the class was gettig a exception. Therefore we must use this adding a subtransaction too.

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to the `DocumentChanged` event before duplicating the symbol. That will provide you with the element ids of all newly created elements. An example of using that is provided by the [place family instance sample](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/06/place-family-instance.html).

After the duplication, unsubscribe again.

You can use the [`Idling` event](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.28) to be notified when the duplication has terminated.